# search for a certain file or items in certain files

Tags: search

I am missing a file. how can I do a search for it on the whole system? default windows search does not return a result. it concerns a .txt file. can I do a search for strings which refer to the content of the file? os: win 7 ult 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Click in the search bar and look for the advanced search options.

In there you will find an option to search file contents in non-indexed locations.

If that doesn't work, I recommend using a tool. Most of the text editors have good multi-file seach. Notepad++ for example.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I search for files containing a specified string in their contents?

You can find all files containing a specific string using the `content:` operator.

For example, to find all text files containg the string "abc" use the following expression in the search box:

```
*.txt content: abc
```